# ebpf kprobe argument not matching the syscall

Tags: python, linux-kernel, ebpf, bcc-bpf

I'm learning eBPF and I'm playing with it in order to understand it better while following the docs but there's something I don't understand why it's not working...

I have this very simple code that stops the code and returns 5.

```
int main() {
   exit(5);
   return 0;
}
```

The `exit` function from the code above  calls the [`exit_group`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html) syscall as can we can see by  using `strace` (image below) yet within my Python code that's using eBPF through bcc the output I get for my `bpf_trace_printk` is the value `208682672` and not the value `5` that the exit_group syscall is called with as I was expecting...

[image: strace return]

```
from bcc import BPF

def main():
    bpftext = """
    #include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>

    void my_exit(struct pt_regs *ctx, int status){
        bpf_trace_printk("%d", status);
    }
    """

    bpf = BPF(text=bpftext)
    fname = bpf.get_syscall_fnname('exit_group')
    bpf.attach_kprobe(event=fname, fn_name='my_exit')

    while True:
        print(bpf.trace_fields())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I've looked into whatever I found online but I couldn't find a solution as I've been investigating this problem for a few days now...

I truly appreciate any help available and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fix

You need to rename your function from `my_exit` to `syscall__exit_group`.

Why does this matter? BPF programs named in this way get special handling from BCC. Here's what the documentation says:

> ##### 8. system call tracepoints
>
> Syntax: `syscall__SYSCALLNAME`
>
> `syscall__` is a special prefix that creates a kprobe for the
> system call name provided as the remainder. You can use it by
> declaring a normal C function, then using the Python
> `BPF.get_syscall_fnname(SYSCALLNAME)` and
> `BPF.attach_kprobe()` to associate it.
>
> Arguments are specified on the function declaration:
> `syscall__SYSCALLNAME(struct pt_regs *ctx, [, argument1 ...])`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> int syscall__execve(struct pt_regs *ctx,
>     const char __user *filename,
>     const char __user *const __user *__argv,
>     const char __user *const __user *__envp)
> {
>     [...]
> }
> ```
>
> This instruments the execve system call.

[Source](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/reference_guide.md#8-system-call-tracepoints).

#### Corrected Code

```py
from bcc import BPF

def main():
    bpftext = """
    #include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>

    void syscall__exit_group(struct pt_regs *ctx, int status){
        bpf_trace_printk("%d", status);
    }
    """

    bpf = BPF(text=bpftext)
    fname = bpf.get_syscall_fnname('exit_group')
    bpf.attach_kprobe(event=fname, fn_name='syscall__exit_group')

    while True:
        print(bpf.trace_fields())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output from the sample program exiting:

```
(b'<...>', 14896, 0, b'd...1', 3996.079261, b'5')
```

#### How it Works

After BCC transforms your BPF program, this results in a slightly different interpretation of the arguments passed. You can use `bpf = BPF(text=bpftext, debug=bcc.DEBUG_PREPROCESSOR)` to see how your code is transformed.

Here's what happens without the `syscall__` prefix:

```c
void my_exit(struct pt_regs *ctx){
 int status = ctx->di;
        ({ char _fmt[] = "%d"; bpf_trace_printk_(_fmt, sizeof(_fmt), status); });
    }
```

This reads in the RDI register and interprets it as the syscall argument.

On the other hand, here's what happens if it's named `syscall__exit_group`:

```c
void syscall__exit_group(struct pt_regs *ctx){
#if defined(CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER) && !defined(__s390x__)
 struct pt_regs * __ctx = ctx->di;
 int status; bpf_probe_read(&status, sizeof(status), &__ctx->di);
#else
 int status = ctx->di;
#endif

        ({ char _fmt[] = "%d"; bpf_trace_printk_(_fmt, sizeof(_fmt), status); });
    }
```

If the `CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_SYSCALL_WRAPPER` is defined (it is on x86_64) then the RDI register is interpreted as a pointer to a `struct pt_regs`, which looks up the RDI register in *that*, which is the first argument to `exit_group()`.

On systems without syscall wrappers, this does the same thing as the previous example.

Comment: Thanks, it works! So if I understood correctly, to create a normal kprobe, the `kprobe__` prefix is unnecessary if we use attach_kprobe, but the `syscall__` prefix is required to create a syscall kprobe right?

Comment: I can get the syscalls through the `strace` command or through the [syscalls man pages](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)... Can you point me to a way to find out how I can find the available non-syscalls kprobes without having to look into the [Linux source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/kprobes/core.c)? Thank you a lot!

Comment: @somerandomdrunkcoder The command `sudo bpftrace -l '*'` can be used to list every kprobe and tracepoint the system has.

Comment: @somerandomdrunkcoder Right.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your probe function should take 3 arguments. They seem to many. In any case, the `struct pt_regs *ctx` you have should already hold any information you need. You should be able to read any register value through dedicated macros (`PT_REGS_xxx`) or manually accessing the structure fields.

The first syscall argument can be extracted with `PT_REGS_PARM1`:

```py
    bpftext = """
    #include <uapi/linux/ptrace.h>

    void my_exit(struct pt_regs *ctx){
        bpf_trace_printk("%ld\\n", PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx));
    }
    """
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time, while copy & pasting my code I didn't notice the extra argument, it was meant to be only 2 arguments (it's fixed now). Using your eBPF code I still get the same return which is `(b'my_c_app', 74837, 0, b'd..31', 10002.827309, b'208387760')`

Comment: @somerandomdrunkcoder So both `PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx)` and `status` have the same wrong value when you print them with `bpf_trace_printk()`?

Comment: yes exactly... replacing the previous eBPF code with the following ```void my_exit(struct pt_regs *ctx, int status){
        bpf_trace_printk("%d", PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx));
    }``` returns  `(b'my_c_app', 75657, 0, b'd..31', 10876.842539, b'209174192 - 209174192')`. The values that get printed keep changing every time my C app is ran... @Marco Bonelli